# Spark Structured Streaming Continuous Mode Reliability

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming

When will Spark Structured Streaming's Continuous Mode be no longer experimental?

I am looking at processing CDC feeds via KAFKA, but note questions about this mode showing data loss from KAFKA.

Comment: I feel like this question is better suited for JIRA or Spark developer mailing list

Comment: @OneCricketeer i am more interested in your opnion on the question.

Comment: Opinion based questions are off-topic ;) Plus, I personally have not used this feature, and would opt for Flink for streaming use cases nowadays, myself

Comment: @OneCricketeer  We cannot always choose the framework.  Anyway thx and see what the closure brings.